# Laravel - Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined [Named Parameters Error]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pdo

I have included all named parameters in query, also took care of named parameter rule mentioned in PDO Documentation (i.e. Reusability of named parameter is not supported). Still Its giving me error, I not able to find error.

```
$leaves = DB::select("SELECT * FROM leaves WHERE emp_id=:emp_id AND status != 'Rejected' AND ((STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN ':from_date1' AND ':to_date1') OR (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN ':from_date2' AND ':to_date2')) OR ((STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= ':from_date3') AND (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= ':to_date3'))",
      [
        'emp_id'=> (int)$request->emp_id, 'from_date1'=>$request->from_date, 'to_date1'=>$request->to_date,
        'from_date2'=>$request->from_date, 'to_date2'=>$request->to_date,
        'from_date3'=>$request->from_date, 'to_date3'=>$request->to_date
      ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using your named parameters incorrectly. Check the [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) documentation and you'll notice that the `'` are *NOT* surrounding the parameter names. Try this query instead:

```
$leaves = DB::select(
   "SELECT * 
    FROM leaves 
    WHERE emp_id=:emp_id AND status != 'Rejected' 
        AND (
           (STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
                BETWEEN :from_date1 AND :to_date1) 
           OR (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') 
                BETWEEN :from_date2 AND :to_date2)
        ) 
        OR (
           (STR_TO_DATE(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d') <= :from_date3) 
           AND (STR_TO_DATE(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d') >= :to_date3)
        )",
      [
        'emp_id'=> (int)$request->emp_id, 'from_date1'=>$request->from_date, 
        'to_date1'=>$request->to_date, 'from_date2'=>$request->from_date, 
        'to_date2'=>$request->to_date, 'from_date3'=>$request->from_date, 
        'to_date3'=>$request->to_date
      ]);
```

Basically, including the `'` around the parameter name makes it so that the driver believes that you are using an actual varchar value inside of your query. In your case, however, you are trying to invoke the replacement.